# Export openlayers current map view to PDF with JsPDF

Tags: export, openlayers, jspdf

I built a map using OpenLayers with different type of data, WMS layer, image Layers. How can i export just the "current map view"? When I want to export PDF in the example, the map view will zoom out.

https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/export-pdf.html

Comment: It's normal... When you see a webmap, it's 72 DPI or 96 dpi resolution. When you want to print, if you choose 300 dpi, it needs to unzoom to get larger view to then rescale your 72 dpi view to produce a 300 dpi view. If you export to high resolution, expect blurry maps export and unzoom...

Comment: so, I cant set no rescale for full resolution current view?

Comment: No. It's always a pain to print because vector can rescale properly whereas if tiles provided are low resolutions, not matter what you do, they will remain blurry for high DPI. See https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/183227/how-print-map-in-ol3-with-top-resolution Sorry, not definitive answer (and I do webmapping since more than 10 years...)

Comment: When i use "printscreen" on my lcd 24-inch monitor, resolution and quality are better than export PDF with 300 DPI

Comment: I just tried to use this with my map and I get "Uncaught DOMException: The operation is insecure. Any idea how to deal with this?